# Cube nets hexomino tilings.

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, recreational-mathematics, tiling, open-problem

I am looking for an $\approx12\times12$ rectangle (small holes and small obtrusions are okay) made entirely of cube net hexominos.

It is my understanding that perfect rectangles, in general, are not possible using the set of $35$ hexominos. I am aware that restricting use to only cube net polyominos exacerbates this limitation.

How close to a rectangle of order $12\times12$ can one get using only cube net hexominos, where the measure of distance to a $12\times12$ rectangle is the number of 'single-square' deletions/additions that would be necessary to delete spurious edges or fill holes.

I would also be interested in known tilings of cube net hexominos, no matter how close they are to a $12\times12$ rectangle.

It's possible this problem may be solvable using computer search. I'm working on that right now.

Answer (score 3):

There is no nice solution with these pieces.  Use [Burr Tools](http://burrtools.sourceforge.net/) to find more solutions.

[image: 11 cube nets]